# Finding the min value of a column for a given interval in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe :

```
                 GDP
Year Quarter        
1955 Q1       109967
     Q2       110087
     Q3       112333
     Q4       111731
1956 Q1       112952
     Q2       112709
     Q3       112601
     Q4       113078
1957 Q1       115315
     Q2       115292
     Q3       114582
     Q4       114775
```

In order to find the minimum value of the specified column I can write as:

```
min(df['GDP'])
```

I wonder how one gets the lowest value of the GDP column for a specified interval? for example for 1955 or between 1955-1956?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`slicers`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers) for selecting and for scalar output select column with `min`:

Notice:

If level `Year` are strings add `''` like `'1955':'1956'` instead `1955:1956`

Or convert strings to numeric by [`MultiIndex.set_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html):

```
df.index = df.index.set_levels(df.index.get_level_values('Year').astype(int), level=0)
```

---

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
a = df.loc[idx[1955:1956], 'GDP'].min()
print (a)
109967

a = df.loc[idx[1955:1956, 'Q2'], 'GDP'].min()
print (a)
110087

a = df.loc[1956, 'GDP'].min()
print (a)
112601
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.loc[idx[1955:1956], 'GDP'])
Year  Quarter
1955  Q1         109967
      Q2         110087
      Q3         112333
      Q4         111731
1956  Q1         112952
      Q2         112709
      Q3         112601
      Q4         113078
Name: GDP, dtype: int64

print (df.loc[idx[1955:1956, 'Q2'], 'GDP'])
Year  Quarter
1955  Q2         110087
1956  Q2         112709
Name: GDP, dtype: int64

print (df.loc[1956, 'GDP'])
Quarter
Q1    112952
Q2    112709
Q3    112601
Q4    113078
Name: GDP, dtype: int64
```

Comment: when i do print (df.loc[idx[1955:1956], 'GDP']) it gives me: Series([], Name: GDP, dtype: object)

Comment: I defined my columns as df.columns = ["Year", "Quarter","GDP"] The row indexers are reading as 0,1,2,3,... so year, quarter and GDP are column index

Comment: I have added that now but when I try pd.IndexSlice[df.loc[1955:1957], 'GDP'] I get TypeError: Level type mismatch: 1955

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the correct result we should use

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice["1955":"1956"], 'GDP'].min()
```

As the years are string type.